# How to get an android Keystore password?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, release

I am a new to android application development. I want to release my app to market. Now I am working in Eclipse. I am stuck at the point of getting a keystore password. How to do this?

Comment: See here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Comment: @shylendra, I am able to export my app in debug mode with the keystore password "android". But when I try to export my app via Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package step, I am getting an error as follows:  Export aborted. Please help.

Comment: To solve issue: Project -> properties, find Android Lint Preferences, in top to right click configure workspace settings... -> unclick "Run full error check when exporting app", apply done.

Comment: Properties is deactivated for me. Why so?

Comment: simplr put cursor on your project and use shortcut as ALT+Enter

Comment: I did the above step, but still I am unable ot export my app in signed application package

Comment: If I am not wrong now, I think I need to change my my app from debug mode to release mode before exporting in signed application package..

Comment: go to Project -> Build Automatically and uncheck it. Then, try to export again using the Android Tools.

Comment: At Keysote selection I am  unable create new keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a Keytool command that generates a private key:

```
keytool \
    -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore \
    -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Running the example command above, Keytool prompts you to provide passwords for the keystore and key, and to provide the Distinguished Name fields for your key. It then generates the keystore as a file called my-release-key.keystore. The keystore and key are protected by the passwords you entered. The keystore contains a single key, valid for 10000 days. The alias is a name that you — will use later, to refer to this keystore when signing your application.

For more information about Keytool, see the documentation at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

To create keystore refer this [link](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/02/sign-your-android-applications-for.html).

You need to sign your app in release mode for that refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

You can see the step by step detailed instructions with screenshots [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Publishing-an-Android-App-to-the-Google-Play-Store/?ALLSTEPS).

Comment: simply click on right mark located at left side of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Jsut check the below url

[publish app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2G5a7gVB4w)

Compiling and signing with Eclipse ADT When using Eclipse with ADT, you can use the Export Wizard to export a signed .apk (and even create a new keystore, if necessary). The Export Wizard performs all the interaction with the Keytool and Jarsigner for you, which allows you to perform signing via a graphical interface instead of the command-line. Because the Export Wizard uses both Keytool and Jarsigner, you should ensure that they are accessible on your computer, as described above in the Basic Setup for Signing.

To create a signed .apk, right-click the project in the Package Explorer and select Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package. (Alternatively, open your AndroidManifest.xml file in Eclipse, open the Overview tab, and click Use the Export Wizard.) The window that appears will display any errors found while attempting to export your application. If no errors are found, continue with the Export Wizard, which will guide you through the process of signing your application, including steps for selecting the private key with which to sign the .apk, or creating a new keystore and private key.

When you complete the Export Wizard, you'll have a signed .apk that's ready for distribution.

and check below link

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode)

Answer (score 0):

Key to Keystore Android from my Windows 10 pro:

1. Open your command prompt
2. Type: `cd\`
3. Type: `cd\`
4. Type:

`cd Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\"your username_of_your_pc_login_without_quotes"\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`